# avoiding code duplication in a java method

Tags: java, callback

Apologies if this has already been asked/answered a thousand times (I did check first).

I'm not a Java programmer by trade and have been tasked with extending an existing Java SOAP service. I'm keen to avoid copy/pasting existing code that I know works, but was wondering what the best options available in java are.

Essentially I have this method already:

```
public String methodThatIDontWantToCopyPaste(
        @WebParam(name = "a", partName = "a") String paramA,
        @WebParam(name = "b", partName = "b") int paramB,
        @WebParam(name = "c", partName = "c") int paramC) {

    // Validate parameters
    if (paramA.isEmpty() || 
            0 == paramB || 
            0 == paramC) {
        return "Invalid request";
    }
    String response = "";

    try {

        // Parmaeters OK, build client
        /*
        lots of generic implementation here
        ...
        XYZ client = ...
        ...
        */

        response = client.specificMethodToHandleABC(paramA, paramB, paramC);

    } catch (SOAPException | IOException ex) {
       // handling omitted

    } 

    return response;
}
```

I want to add several new/similar methods, but each will have:

1. A different set of parameters
2. A different block of code to validate the parameters (the above code is trivial, but some will be more detailed
3. A different implementation of the line:
   response = client.specificMethodToHandleABC(a, b, c);
   i.e. where a different method will be called, with a different set of arguments

I'd normally go for a callback in my usual programming language, but it's a proprietary language and not as powerful as Java, so I wanted to know what the best option was?

Comment: You probably could use method parameter validation of the bean validation api. Or in the simplest case just extract a method that does the parameter validation. But as long as your methods are all doing different things with different sets of parameters, there isn't just much room for making things more abstract/generic. Don't try to over engineer a solution.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker thanks for the advice. I went with this option in the end. There were less commonalities between the code than I thought there were, so it would have just complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar setting, I used callbacks/anonymous classes by calling a method out of every endpoint and passing a callback for every variable part into the method, like the following

```
public String methodA(final int param1, final String param2) throws Exception {
    return this.call(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return param1 != 0 && param2 != null;
        }
    });
}


public String methodB(final String param1, final String param2) throws Exception {
    return this.call(new Callable<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return param1 != null && param2 != null;
        }
    });
}

private String call(Callable<Boolean> validationCallable) throws Exception {
    // static code similar to all methods

    assert validationCallable.call().equals(Boolean.TRUE);

    // static code similar to all methods

    return ""; // probably result based on another callable
}
```